# Enable SSL in QGIS server

Tags: qgis-server, wmts, ogc, ssl, http

## Context

I have a [dockerized QGIS server](https://hub.docker.com/r/camptocamp/qgis-server) project running and serving tiles through an OGC WMTS.

E.g. this URL:

> http://{baseurl}/?SERVICE=WMTS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetTile&LAYER={my_custom_layer}&STYLE=default&TileMatrixSet=EPSG:3857&TileMatrix=22&TileRow=1079050&TileCol=2274423&format=image/png

shows me a tile in Firefox:

[image: WMTS tile sample]

This works great.

But this is an HTTP request and I need to enable [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS).

If I query the same tile using HTTPS instead of HTTP, I have to wait forever, nothing happens, and the server stdout doesn't display any incoming requests.

## Question

How could I enable HTTPS in my QGIS server?
I didn't find any information about it, either [here](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/index.html) or [there](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/qgis_server/index.html).

## Environment

The aforementioned docker image hosted on a Ubuntu 18.04 server machine.
Which gives:

```
# qgis --version
QGIS 3.10.6-A Coruña 'A Coruña' (ec80021f49)
```

Comment: Looks like a folder needs to be write-able according to this info (at the bottom) https://issues.qgis.org/issues/16462

Comment: Thanks. But it's not clear to me where should I add this `/srv/qgis/.qgis2` folder; inside the docker container or on the machine hosting that container? And in which file should I append the line `FcgidInitialEnv HOME "/srv/qgis"`? (I'm not a web server expert).

Answer (score 0):

Same issue,

I guess that configuring nginx/apache for ssl and isolate gqis ports inside the docker network may be a solution.